# How to find intersection between all possible pairs of sets in a 2-column table?

Tags: r, dplyr, set-intersection

I want to calculate an overlap coefficient between sets. My data comes as a 2-column table, such as:

```r
df_example <- 
  tibble::tribble(~my_group, ~cities,
                   "foo",   "london",
                   "foo",   "paris", 
                   "foo",   "rome", 
                   "foo",   "tokyo",
                   "foo",   "oslo",
                   "bar",   "paris", 
                   "bar",   "nyc",
                   "bar",   "rome", 
                   "bar",   "munich",
                   "bar",   "warsaw",
                   "bar",   "sf", 
                   "baz",   "milano",
                   "baz",   "oslo",
                   "baz",   "sf",  
                   "baz",   "paris")
```

In `df_example`, I have 3 sets (i.e., `foo`, `bar`, `baz`), and members of each set are given in `cities`.

I would like to end up with a table that intersects all possible pairs of sets, and specifies the size of the smaller set in each pair. This will give rise to calculating an *overlap coefficient* for each pair of sets.

(Overlap coefficient = number of common members / size of smaller set)

*Desired Output*

```r
## # A tibble: 3 × 4
##   combination n_instersected_members size_of_smaller_set  overlap_coeff
##   <chr>                        <dbl>               <dbl>          <dbl>
## 1 foo*bar                          2                   5           0.4 
## 2 foo*baz                          3                   4           0.75
## 3 bar*baz                          2                   4           0.5
```

Is there a simple enough way to get this done with *dplyr* verbs? I've tried

```r
df_example |> 
  group_by(my_group) |> 
  summarise(intersected = dplyr::intersect(cities))
```

But this won't work, obviously, because `dplyr::intersect()` expects two vectors. Is there a way to get to the desired output similar to my *dplyr* direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `combn`

```
do.call(
    rbind,
    combn(
        with(
            df_example,
            split(cities, my_group)
        ),
        2,
        \(x)
        transform(
            data.frame(
                combo = paste0(names(x), collapse = "-"),
                nrIntersect = sum(x[[1]] %in% x[[2]]),
                szSmallSet = min(lengths(x))
            ),
            olCoeff = nrIntersect / szSmallSet
        ),
        simplify = FALSE
    )
)
```

which gives

```
    combo nrIntersect szSmallSet olCoeff
1 bar-baz           2          4     0.5
2 bar-foo           2          5     0.4
3 baz-foo           2          4     0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to organize the data would be to use a tabular form (we can use a sparse Matrix to save memory if needed):

```
#library(Matrix)
tab = xtabs( ~ cities + my_group, df_example, sparse = TRUE)
```

Then, all other variables can be calculated as:

```
n_intersected_members = crossprod(tab)
size_of_smaller_set = outer(cs <- colSums(tab), cs, pmin)
overlap_coeff = n_intersected_members / size_of_smaller_set
#overlap_coeff
#3 x 3 Matrix of class "dsyMatrix"
#    bar baz foo
#bar 1.0 0.5 0.4
#baz 0.5 1.0 0.5
#foo 0.4 0.5 1.0
```

And retrieve the `lower.tri` of each object if needed.

Comment: Nice approach, +1! BTW, `table(df_example)` should be more concise and efficient.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding : Agree, `table` is straightforward. I, deliberately, went with `xtabs` to store in a sparse matrix